# Collectionview not show JSON Parsing image

Tags: ios, json, uicollectionview

i am newbie in iOS Development. I want to parsing image from web services and shown in to collection-view custom cell. then i write code like as

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)
#define imageURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/gallery_image.php"]





  @interface CollectionViewController ()
  {
NSData *data;
  }

@end

 @implementation CollectionViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imageURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});

[self.imagecollection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Custum" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
} 
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
NSError* error;
self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
self.imagesa=[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
if (self.imagesa.count) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.imagecollection reloadData];
    });
}
NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imagesa);
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.imagesa.count;
}
-(Custum *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Custum *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSString *img2=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
NSLog(@"IMages Name %@",img2);
cell.galleryImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:img2];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.galleryImage];
return cell;
}
```

Here my custom collection view cell image view is gallery image.

then my image was parsed from the web services but not shown in to collection view cell please give me right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a custom UICollectionViewCell class that has a UIImageView property, init it with a frame that's the same as your UICOllectionView's frame.

Then in your viewController's cellForRow method, use SDWebImage to asynchronously set your cell's custom photo.

### Cell Header File

```
@interface CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *photo;

@end
```

### Cell Implementation File

```
@implementation CustomCell

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self)
    {
        self.photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.photo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.photo];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

### View Controller Implementation File

```
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] init....];
    self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // using SDWebImage to download photo asynchronously.

    [cell.photo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:[json valueForKey:@"imageURL"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImage.png"]];


}
```

### Spinner

Modify your custom cell class to include a new UIActivitiyIndicator property:

```
@interface CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *photo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

@end

@implementation CustomCell

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self)
    {
        self.photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.photo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        // might or might not need to set frame of spinner

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.photo];
        [self.photo addSubview:self.spinner];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Then change the SDWebImage call to the one with the completion block:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // using SDWebImage to download photo asynchronously.

    [cell.spinner startAnimating];    

    [cell.photo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:[json valueForKey:@"imageURL"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImage.png"] options:0 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) { 

        // tell spinner to stop animating after image finished downloading
        [cell.spinner stopAnimating];

    }];
}
```

Comment: i want to put a spinner in to collection view cell when image was loading at placeholder image's place it was possible?if it was possible then please tell me How it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

img2 is a link to the image, so try to add:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:img2];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.galleryImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

instead of `cell.galleryImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:img2];`